# Conditionally Render CSS Based On Route (React)

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router

Here is my App.js component so far:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
         <Route exact path='/' component={HomepageLayout} />
         <Route exact path='/post/:id' component={Post}/>

        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I need to render the CSS value of a class based on the route that is being rendered. When the HomepageLayout component is rendered, I need the following:

styles.css

```css
 .ui.inverted.vertical.center.aligned.segment{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;  
 }
```

Then, I need to change the values for this target when the Post component is rendered so that the styles are basically removed:

styles.css

```css
 .ui.inverted.vertical.center.aligned.segment{
    position: none;
    left: none;
    top: none;
    width: none;
    z-index: none;  
 }
```

Is there a way to change the styles for a particular CSS class tag based on the route? I have seen examples using , but is there a way to do this with  / ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use it like this

```
<Component header />

// component

const Component = ({header}) => {

  const conditionalClass = header ? 'yesHeader' : 'noHeader';
  return (
   <p className={conditionalClass}>this is </p>
  )

}
```

you can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) as well

Comment: Thanks - ClassNames helped.